# Incorrect execution inside if else loop

Tags: excel, if-statement, vba

I have the following code. But the `if-else` loop executes not correctly. I.e. `MsgBox (Hour(strTime))` prints `14`,

So `If (Hour(strTime) = 17 & Minute(time) = 31 & Weekday(time) <> 1 & Weekday(time) <> 2)` should **not** execute. But it does it anyway every time. Appreciate if someone see any mistakes in the code. Best Regards

```
Private RunWhen As Date
Private Const StartTime As Date = #2:14:30 PM#
Private Const EndTime As Date = #5:34:55 PM#
Private Const cRunInterval = "00:01:00"
Private Const cRunWhat = "Data" ' the name of the procedure to run


Sub StartTimer()
Dim strTime
strTime = time

    If RunWhen = 0 Then
        RunWhen = StartTime
    Else
        RunWhen = RunWhen + TimeValue(cRunInterval)
    End If
    MsgBox (Hour(strTime))
    If (RunWhen <= EndTime & Weekday(time) <> 1 & Weekday(time) <> 2) Then
        If (Hour(strTime) = 17 & Minute(time) = 31 & Weekday(time) <> 1 & Weekday(time) <> 2) Then
            'MsgBox ("Mail")
            Call CDO_Mail_Small_Text
        Else
            If (Hour(strTime) = 17 & Minute(time) = 33 & Weekday(time) <> 1 & Weekday(time) <> 2) Then
                MsgBox ("clear")
                Call ClearData
            Else
            Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:=cRunWhat, Schedule:=True
            End If
        End If
    End If


End Sub

Sub Data()
Dim RowNo As Long
Dim RowNo2 As Long
RowNo = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Row
RowNo2 = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Sheets(1).Cells(RowNo2, 15) = Sheets(1).Cells(RowNo, 11) 
    Sheets(1).Cells(RowNo2, 16) = Sheets(1).Cells(RowNo, 12) 
    Sheets(1).Cells(RowNo2, 17) = Sheets(1).Cells(RowNo, 13) 
    Sheets(1).Cells(RowNo2, 14) = time

    StartTimer ' Reschedule the procedure
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your issues is with using `&` instead of the boolean operator `AND`.

```
Sub StartTimer()
Dim strTime
strTime = time

If RunWhen = 0 Then
    RunWhen = StartTime
Else
    RunWhen = RunWhen + TimeValue(cRunInterval)
End If
MsgBox (Hour(strTime))
If (RunWhen <= EndTime AND Weekday(time) <> 1 AND Weekday(time) <> 2) Then
    If (Hour(strTime) = 17 AND Minute(time) = 31 AND Weekday(time) <> 1 AND Weekday(time) <> 2) Then
        'MsgBox ("Mail")
        Call CDO_Mail_Small_Text
    Else
        If (Hour(strTime) = 17 AND Minute(time) = 33 AND Weekday(time) <> 1 & Weekday(time) <> 2) Then
            MsgBox ("clear")
            Call ClearData
        Else
        Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:=cRunWhat, Schedule:=True
        End If
    End If
End If


End Sub
```

Also, I am not sure if you are calling this sub with arguments from another routine, but when I tested it I was getting numerous variables that weren't defined.

**It is good practice to ensure `Option Explicit`** is declared at the beginning of your module.

This ensures all variables are declared and it has saved me from countless hours of tracing back variables due to typos.

Comment: Thanks, I have been programming to much javascript... Forgot that VBA has `AND` :P I dont get any undefined errors and have option explicit now.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped. I completely understand the difficulties in switching languages. I am sure it happens to the best of us!